# Unable to set text in TextView inside static inner class

Tags: android, textview, broadcastreceiver

I have created an application in which i am sending a broadcast to my activity and in this broadcast i am sending two values, one is type and other is a badge, i am receiving these values in my inner class which is extending BroadcastReceiver  but when i am going to set these values in the TextView of my main class then it is not setting these values, i am not able to understand why is this happening.

Following is my main acitivity in which inner class is present, and it is extending BroadcastReceiver :-

```
import java.util.List;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.ViewAnimator;



  public class TabActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

        static String type;
        static String badges;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ................
        }

        public static class TabBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver
        {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                SharedPreferences shrd = context.getSharedPreferences("Gallery", context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                type = shrd.getString("type", "null");
                badges = shrd.getString("badge_count", "null");


                    badge_tips_text.setText(badge);

                /*Editor edit =  shrd.edit();
                edit.remove("type");*/

                Toast.makeText(context, "" + type + "\n" + badge_tips_text.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

I am receiving the values but unable to set them in TextView, please reply any help will be appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: Your broadcast receiver class is not a visual component, start an activity instead. Also, _static_ inner classes don't have direct access to  outer instance variables.

Comment: it is giving me an error i.e.  "No enclosing instance of the type NissanTabActivity is accessible in scope"

Comment: @Singularity then how can i access to my textview inside this receiver, any idea ?

Comment: @SalmanKhan : but you have Activity name TabActivity instead of NissanTabActivity so use TabActivity instead of NissanTabActivity or in which Activity you have TabBroadcast . see my edit answer

Comment: @SalmanKhan : and no need to declare TabBroadcast as static just remove static from it

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K : it is again giving an error that "badge_tips_text cannot be resolved or is not a field", it is a part of my upper class which is NissanTabActivity

Comment: @SalmanKhan :  plz see this example http://stepapp.googlecode.com/svn-history/r7/StepApp/src/org/me/stepapp/MainActivity.java

Comment: @SalmanKhan : make sure u have declare badge_tips_text textView at class level i mean before onCreate of Activity

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K : if i am not declaring the inner class as static it is giving me an error that i can't instantiate the broadcast receiver. The app is just crashing.

Comment: @SalmanKhan : i have already shared an example link with u in which author is doing same as u are looking for . i think u will need to post full class code with TabBroadcast . then i will try to help u friend

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K: i just want to update my UI in my BroadcastReceiver, and it is to set the textview.

Answer (score 0):

TabBroadcast is inner class of an Activity then try as to access UI elements :

```
public class TabActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

        static String type;
        static String badges;
        public TextView badge_tips_text;  //<<<< TextView declare here
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ................
           //<<<< initilze  TextView   here after setContentView 
        }
public static class TabBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver
        {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(TabActivity.this.badge_tips_text !=null)
                    TabActivity.this.badge_tips_text.setText(badge);
                     // your code here ...

            }

        }

}
```

and make sure you have initialized TextView before calling TextView.setText

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference instance(non static) `TextView` from a static inner class. Instead, pass the stuff required through constructor:

```
public static class TabBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{
  private final TextView textview;

  public TabBroadcast(TextView t){
    this.textview = t;
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    t.setText("works");
  } 
}
```

Comment: i am calling this broadcast from another broadcast class which is outside of my Activity. Basically what i am doing is as soon as i get notification in notification bar i raise broadcast to this class.

Comment: And this class has no means to create a context/activity/service or any thing visual to show to the user.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the broadcast receiver is running on a different thread. Try using a handler that is passed from your activity:

Where you create your broadcast class use:

```
new TabBroadcast(new Handler());
```

Pass the handler through the TabBroadcast constructor and now inside of your TabBroadcast onReceive, you can do the following:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myTextview.setText("Text");
    }
});
```

You will need to set myTextview as final